# How does lodash have a build script that resides in a directory that isn't in the repository?

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash

I'm trying to discover best practices for building a library and looking through famous library code. I looked at [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/package.json) and saw that the build scripts all reference a `lib` directory that doesn't exist. If I clone this repository, how can it build if these files don't exist in the repository?

Comment: I checked the link because I thought the answer might be obvious, but it doesn't even seem to be available when downloading via `npm`: https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4/lib/main/build-dist.js

Comment: I was initially curious because it said the "main" file was lodash.js but this didn't exist. "Fair enough", I thought. Maybe it is created in the build script. "WTF", I thought.

Comment: Perhaps [this warning](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md#construction-notice-construction) is relevant? Also, [`lodash.js`](https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.js) _does_ exist when downloading via `npm`, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We used to use [lodash-cli](https://github.com/lodash-archive/lodash-cli) to modularize and bundle individual method packages. However, in v5 we'll stick to a single modular package.

[Reference](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3398)